# Handling Signal without interrupting IO

Tags: c++, io, signals

How is it possible to catch a signal by a process , handle it such that a current ongoing IO output is not interrupted?

Can this be achieved by calling all registered callbacks `handleExit()` in `exitSignalHandling` till one `handleExit()` returns a status which tells that it handled the exit signal. The signal is handled in objectB if it has been marked to handle the exit, this is the case when the process is currently inside the relevant function which need special care :

```
void exitSignalHandling(){
    /** call all registered callbacks */

}
while(1){
    objectB.compute();     
    objectA.write(some data) /* when process enters: set flag to handle exit signal , objectB registered a call back objectB::handleExit()*/  
}

class objectA{
    bool handleExit(){
        if( handleExit == true){
         exitAfterWrite = true;
         return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    write(){
       handleExit=true;   
       /*write data*/
       if(exitAfterWrite){ exit(SUCCESS) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any delivered signal will interrupt ongoing IO. You cannot do much about it. You need to wrap IO calls in while loops and test for `errno == EINTR`. Are you experiencing an XY problem? What is your use case?

Comment: Signals are usually operating system specific (even if the C11 standard mentions them a little). For Linux, read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well obviously, the problem is that by handling a signal, you're exiting the object context and are back to static C code.

What you need to do is re-enter the object context with e.g. a singleton class or a global variable. This class would act as the holder class for all the objects that are registered for signal-uninterruptible I/O.

There are different ways of doing this. You can either employ an abstract class with `bool handleExit() = 0;` method. Other solution would be binding a handler method with `std::bind(&class::handler, this)` and storing it in a container.

When you start/end signal-uninterruptible I/O, you need to register/unregister your handler object with the holder. I think that using dynamic polymorphism would be the easiest way here.

I also have to state that your idea is not exactly thought-through. If I call `handleExit`, I get a value, whether exit was already set before. I don't see any use of it. But that's a minor problem.

What intrigues me the most is the use of `exit` call. Using this way of ending the application is not very bright. Imagine you would have two objects doing uninterruptible I/O at the time a interrupting signal comes. Only the first one will finish, the second one will still get killed along the way by the `exit` call from the first object.

Generally, I think it would be much better idea to create one class that is responsible for all the signal handling and decides to kill the application when no I/O is pending.